# Problem with Tkinter ttk theme in changing between light and dark (UI automatically scale)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, themes

i'm using Python and Tkinter for GUI. I've a function using switch and ttk for switching between light and dark mode:

```
def ThemeChanger():
    if screen.tk.call("ttk::style", "theme", "use") == "sun-valley-dark":
        # Set light theme
        screen.tk.call("set_theme", "light")
    else:
        # Set dark theme
        screen.tk.call("set_theme", "dark"
```

But when I clicked into the switch, all the UI automatically scales a litter bit:

[image: Light Mode]

[image: Dark Mode]

It will scale larger if i use tabs or table in ttk Tkinter, and won't scale back when switch to light mode, it scales more and more when I clicked into theme switch button:

```
def change_theme():
    # NOTE: The theme's real name is sun-valley-<mode>
    if root.tk.call("ttk::style", "theme", "use") == "sun-valley-dark":
        # Set light theme
        root.tk.call("set_theme", "light")
    else:
        # Set dark theme
        root.tk.call("set_theme", "dark")
```

[image: Unchange]

[image: 1st change]

[image: 2nd change]

[image: 3rd change]

[image: 4th change]

I don't know how to fix this. I would so appreciate if anyone can recommend me improving these. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I partially fixed this bug, see [this](https://github.com/rdbende/Sun-Valley-ttk-theme/issues/6#issuecomment-1000247868). But the Treeview still scales, and I can't figure out, why. This strange problem applies to all third-party ttk themes that have some kind of treeview styling, but not to others.

Comment: This issue is fixed in the [latest release](https://github.com/rdbende/Sun-Valley-ttk-theme/releases/tag/v2.0), thanks to the great Tk dev team for coming up with a brilliant solution to this bug ([ticket](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview?name=bc602049ab)).